# OS X rpc.statd warning failed to contact host

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

When I log into my mac on 10.6.3 I get the following error in my console

```
29/05/2010 19:11:43 prometheus rpc.statd[109] Warning Failed to contact host aphrodite.lan: RPC: Unknown host
```

Now I know that rpc is trying to contact a non existent host but what I can't figure out is why and how to stop it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you've got Prometheus set to NFS-mount a filesystem from Aphrodite?

Comment: Nope, I did once but not anymore

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- open shell
- rpc.statd -l #shows all hosts in the statd database
- sudo rpc.statd -N Hostname #to remove the entry

the error should be gone then.